# Webcam Solution

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

Is anyone successfully embedding webcam videos in nodes where those videos are private on the hosting service? I especially would appreciate hearing about OG-supporting solutions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to look at a hosting provider that provides this service. I'd search there before applying it to Drupal specifically. Usually a provider will have implementation instructions